# Items of Grid View gets truncated from bottom

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

I have a windows store apps. I am displaying my dynamic content in a grid view.
My problem is that the items get truncated from bottom. The grid defined is at the bottom of the below XAML named "ContentGrid".

Because i have given maxRoworColumns as 10. With my current screen resolution or screen size it can only see till 9th element and its get truncated. The 10th element is hidden.I can see the 11th element in the next column.

Below is my XAML

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="BackButtonColumn" Width="auto">
        <Button x:Name="backButton"                 
                Margin="0,109,0,0"                  
                Click="OnBackButtonClicked"                                         
                Style="{StaticResource NavigationBackButtonNormalStyle}" Background="Black"                                
                VerticalAlignment="Top"                  
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"                
                RequestedTheme="Light"                                
                Foreground="Black" BorderBrush="Black" 
                Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock x:Uid="AppName"                                                   
                   Foreground="{StaticResource AppBlueBrush}"                       
                   Style="{StaticResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"                       
                   Margin="-10,30,0,0"                        
                   FontSize="56"                      
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"                       
                   Name="ProducName"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="Title"                               
                   Foreground="Black"                        
                   Margin="0,40,0,0"                         
                   FontSize="26" 
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI"/>

        <TextBlock x:Name="FolderContentStatusMsg"                               
                   Foreground="Gray"                        
                   Margin="0,40,0,0"                         
                   FontSize="18" 
                   Visibility="Collapsed"
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"/>


        **<GridView x:Name="ContentGrid"                          
                  Height="auto"                          
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Folder}"                               
                  VerticalAlignment="Stretch"                       
                  HorizontalAlignment="Left"                      
                  CanReorderItems="False"                       
                  CanDragItems="False"                             
                  ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextListFileTemplate}"                                                                   
                  Margin="0,30,0,0"    
                  ContainerContentChanging="ContentGrid_ContainerContentChanging"
                  Tapped="onTapped">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <ItemsWrapGrid  Orientation="Vertical" MaximumRowsOrColumns="10"/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>**
```

thanks and Regards,
Saurav

Comment: Check the `ScrollViewer` control.

Comment: thanks @dbvega for the response. I enabled scroll mode by adding the following elements to the grid view control  ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Enabled"
                      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"> But it didn't still work

Comment: Take your GridView out of that StackPanel

Comment: Great...thanks Chris...i created two rows ...one for the StackPanel and GridView and it worked.